# Conditionally launch Spring Cloud Task on a specific node of Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, spring-batch, etl, batch-processing, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am building a data pipeline for batch processing. And I find that Spring Cloud Data Flow is a quite attractive framework to use. Without much knowledge in SCDF and Kubernetes, I am not sure whether it is possible to conditionally launch a Spring Cloud Task on a specific machine.

Suppose I have two physical servers that are for running the batch process (Server A and Server B). By default, I would like  my Spring cloud task to be launched on Server A. If the Server A is shut down, the task should be deployed on server B. Can Kubernetes / SCDF handle this kind of mechanism? I am wondering whether the `nodeselector` is the thing that I should look into.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can pass `deployment.nodeSelector` as a deployment property when launching the task.

The `deployment.nodeSelector` is a Kubernetes deployment property and hence, you need to pass something like this:

```
task launch mytask --properties "deployer.<taskAppName>.kubernetes.deployment.nodeSelector=foo1:bar1,foo2:bar2"
```

You can check the list of supported Kubernetes deployer properties [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-kubernetes-deployer)